# Get error No Private Key when digitally sign pdf by .cer file with X509Certificate

Tags: c#, asp.net, certificate, x509certificate, x509certificate2

i am digitally sign pdf by using .cer file with X509Certificate. but on IExternalSignature i didn't get signature. errors come "No Private Key"

Here is my code

```
string uc= Server.MapPath("~/username.cer");
System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate cert = new System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate();
cert.Import(uc);
X509Certificate2 signatureCert = new X509Certificate2(cert);
IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(signatureCert, "SHA-1");
```

on last line i get error "No Private Key"

suggest me solution

Comment: `.cer` file doesn't contain private key, it contains only public part of the X.509 certificate. Suggest solution? Get certificate with private key. If it is a file, it is usually with a `.pfx` or with `.p12` file extension.

Comment: @Crypt32 thanks for reply . any example suggest o me by .pfx file sign the pdf with #x509certificate2 or #pkcs11

Comment: Im guessing same code, just that the file should be .pfx instead of .cer